# A few questions about integrating AudioKinetic Wwise and Unity

Tags: unity

I'm new to Wwise and to using it with Unity, and though I have gotten the integration to work, I'm still dealing with some loose ends and have a few questions:
(I'm on Unity 4.3 as of now but I think it shouldn't make any difference)

1. **The base path:** The Wwise documentation implies you set this in the
   `AkGlobalSoundEngineInitializer` `basePath` public ivar, which is
   exposed to the editor. However, I found that this variable is not
   really used. Instead, the path is hardcoded to
   `/Audio/GeneratedSoundBanks` in `AkBankPath`. I had to modify both
   scripts to actually look in the path that I set in the editor
   property. What's the deal with this? Just sloppyness or am I missing
   something?
2. **Also about paths:** since I'm on Mac, I'm using Unity natively under
   OS X and in tadem, the Wwise authoring tool via VMWare and I share
   the OS X Unity project folder so I can generate the soundbanks into
   the assets folder. However, the authoring tool (downloaded the
   latest one for Windows) doesn't automatically generate any
   "platform-specific" subfolders for my wwise files. That is, again,
   the Unity integration scripts assume the path to be
   `/Audio/GeneratedSoundBanks/<my-platform>/` which in my case would be
   Mac (I set the authoring tool to generate for Mac). The
   documentation says wwise will automatically generate the
   platform-specific folders but it just dumps all the stuff in
   `GeneratedSoundBanks`. Am I missing some setting? cause right now I
   just manually create the `/Mac` folder.
3. **The C# methods `AkSoundEngine.PostEvent` and `AkSoundEngine.LoadBank`**
   for instance, have a few overloads, including ones where I can refer
   to the soundbanks or events by their ID. However, if I try to use
   these, for instance:

   AkSoundEngine.LoadBank(,
       AkSoundEngine.AK_DEFAULT_POOL_ID)

   where the int I got from the .h header, I get `Ak_Fail`. If I use the overloads that
   reference the objects by string name then it works. What gives?
4. **Converting the ID header to C#:** The integration comes with a C# script that seems to fork a process
   to call Python in turn to covert the C++ header into a C# script.
   This always fails unless I manually execute the Python script myself
   from outside Unity. Might be a permissions thing, but has anyone
   experienced this?
5. **The Profiler:** I set up the Unity player to run in the background and
   am using the "Profile" version of the plugin. However, when I start
   the Unity OS X standalone app, the profiler in VMWare does not see
   it. This I'm thinking might just be that I'm trying to see a running
   instance of the sound engine inside an OS X binary from a Windows
   virtual machine. But I'm just wondering if anyone has gotten the
   Windows profiler to see an OS X Unity binary.
6. **Different versions of the integration plugin:** It's not clear to me from the documentation whether I have
   to manually (or write a script to do it) remove the "Profile"
   version and install the "Release" version when I'm going to do a
   Release build or if I should install both version in Unity and it'll
   select the right one.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be best to ask questions like this on the forum for the product.

Comment: I did, but no one even looked at the question. If their site had the tumble weed badge I would have gotten it :/

Answer (score 1):

So I just ran into this issue myself and it seems that all that's missing is setting up your Environment Variables to recognize the python path so that python can be run from anywhere.

In case you or anyone else reading this doesn't know how to modify environment variables here's a step by step.

1. Click your start button
2. Right Click "Computer"
3. Choose "Properties"
4. On the left, click "Advanced system settings"
5. Under the Advanced tab click "Environment Variables"
6. In the "System variables" box, find and select the "Path" variable and click "Edit..."

This variable should already contain several paths used by your system, don't touch those.
7. At the end of the list of paths add your python install path preceded by a ; (the delimiter between paths)
8. Hit Ok and try to run the Wwise menu option inside of Unity, should work fine now.

I hope this helped you and anyone else setting this up. Good luck!